# Pandoc Lua Filter: How to access the title variable?

Tags: lua, pandoc

My document looks like this

```
---
title: 'Test'
---

lorem ipsum
```

I want to access the title variable to print it like this:

```
function Image (elem)
elem.attributes.caption = 'Image of chapter ' .. title
return elem
```

The caption of all images should be: `'Image of chapter Test'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested), inspired by [the docs](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#setting-the-date-in-the-metadata):

```lua
title = nil

function Meta(m)
  title = m.title
  return m
end

function Image (elem)
  elem.attributes.caption = 'Image of chapter ' .. title
  return elem
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables like properties at the meta object, or you can access them like elements of a dictionary. The latter is especially important if you have variables in your YAML block that contain hyphens, like e.g. `payment-due`.

```lua
function Meta(meta)
    print(meta.title)
    print(meta["payment-due"])
```

The type of such a variable is `table`. You can check that using `type()`:

```lua
    print(type(meta.title))
    print(type(meta["payment-due"]))
```

To convert it into a string, you can use `pandoc.utils.stringify()`. Just make sure that the value is actually set and is not `nil`:

```lua
    if meta.title ~= nil then
      local title = pandoc.utils.stringify(meta.title)
      print(title)
    end
```

Hint: don't use `tostring()`. Your variable will then look like `[Str "Test"]`.