# Quarto make a shortcode that reads content from the document

Tags: pandoc, quarto

I want to make a Quarto extension that extracts some information from the existing document, and dumps it when the user places a shortcode. For example, let's say I want to count the number of images in the document and then output it when the user adds `{{< imgcount >}}`.

However, [Quarto shortcodes](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/shortcodes.html) don't seem to have the capacity to access the rest of the document. [Quarto Filters](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/filters.html) can access the document content, by defining element filters. However, they can't define shortcodes. You can define a Quarto extension with both a filter and a shortcode, but it's not clear to me if these can communicate with each other.

Is there an elegant way to therefore solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can communicate using the `meta` variable, which is accessible for the `Meta` filter and for shortcodes. The meta filter is run *after* the element filters, so you can count the images first and set the meta value after that.

Filter `countimages.lua`:

```lua
nrimgs = 0

function Meta(m)
  m.totalimgs = nrimgs
  return m
end

function Image (elem)
  nrimgs = nrimgs + 1
  return elem
end
```

Shortcode `imgcount.lua`:

```lua
return {
  ['imgcount'] = function(args, kwargs, meta) 
    return pandoc.Str(meta.totalimgs)
  end
}
```

Quarto document:

```markdown
---
title: "Count images"
filters:
  - countimages.lua
---

This document has {{< imgcount >}} images.

![Elephant](elephant_small.png)

![Lion](lion_small.png)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Do you think this is a public Quarto or pandoc API?

Comment: @Migwell the `Meta()` and `Image()` functions come from the Pandoc API, I found them through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912263/pandoc-lua-filter-how-to-access-the-title-variable. The shortcodes functionality is provided by Quarto.